# Web part error message: A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported

Tags: web-part

I have a custom made Web Part that I want to add to a page in my SharePoint site. But I'm having this error message every time:

> A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type SharePointProject1.WebPartName.WebPartName, SharePointProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=32e59cf2728706a0 could not be found or it is not registered as safe.

I have activated the solution feature at the site collection level. 
I have also ensured that the safe control entries are enabled.  as well as editing the xml file to set `SafeControl` entry to `true`. Then I removed and uninstalled the solution and installed it again. But still same error message. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What it could be:

1. Your Web part is not correctly declared as Safe in the web.config. Do you see the web.config `SafeControl` entry in the wb.config? Was is added automatically? Can you share it with us so we can check together?
2. The class `SharePointProject1.WebPartName.WebPartName` is not declared `public`.
3. The DLL is not in the GAC neither in the app_bin folder. How do you deploy the solution?

Comment: I have checked in web.config, I couldn't find the control there. Do I add it manually or it should be added???

Comment: the class is public and for no.3 how do I confirm this? you mean the dll of the solution file?

Comment: The `SafeControl` entry should be in the web.config file of the SharePoint Web application (e.g. `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80`). If it's not, maybe you did not deploy correctly the WSP package, or maybe not against the correct Web application. How did you deploy the WSP?

Comment: As for your second question: yup, I mean the DLL from the solution; should be deployed into the GAC when you deploy the WSP file.

Comment: ya you were right, it was an issue with the wsp deployment. now it's working. I have uninstalled and removed wsp package, deleted existing webparts from the gallery then reinstalled it again on the web app. it is working now. thanks!!